# Touched wires do i need to replace

Tags: wire

I was changing out my hot water heater, I had the water main shut off and two breakers for the mester suite apparently there was a third. When i removed the wires from the old so i could cap them they touched nice arch both ( not the ground) now have dark tips. I checked my breaker box nothing was tripped.. My questions are,
1. Will this cable type wire still work?
2. Do I need to replace this cable type wire all the way back to the main box?

Comment: You say you had an arc and the wires charred, but nothing tripped at the breaker? This alone enough for me to suggest if not replace, at least trace where wires go to and why there is no fuse there.

Comment: From reading your note you say " two breakers for the mester suite apparently there was a third" ? What do you mean "Mester Suite" ? I assumed you meant Master panel.. but in reading further I'm not sure.. If you meant "master suite".. then just turning off the breakers for the Master bedroom will NOT shut down the water heater.. I am assuming your heater is a 220 or 240 volt heater.. is that correct ? Okay...If your heater is 240 volt and if you really did turn off the proper breakers .. there is NO WAY touching the two hot leg wires would cause an arch.. Something is not right. IT could be t

Comment: Even if the ends of the wires burned slightly they can be trimmed, I would find the breaker that turns off this cable and make sure it is functional, for a good breaker it is not unusual for a light contact not to trip the breaker but create a nice arc. The one case would cause me concern if the panel is an fpe federal Pacific panel these are known to have failures. But for most standard panels I would not be concerened.

Comment: Use a non contact voltage tester to confirm that the power is off. You must find all the breakers that serve the circuit(s) to the heater and turn them off. How many cables go to the heater?